# Angular 5 ngx-intl-tel-input error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-intl-tel-input,
I have my module.ts with:

```
import {NgxIntlTelInputModule} from "ngx-intl-tel-input";
import {BsDropdownModule} from "ngx-bootstrap";
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgxIntlTelInputModule,
        BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

and html code:

```
<h1>
        {{phone_number}}
</h1>
<ngx-intl-tel-input [(value)]="phone_number"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

but all the time I receive following error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(...)[BsDropdownDirective ->
>   ComponentLoaderFactory]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[BsDropdownDirective -> ComponentLoaderFactory]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ComponentLoaderFactory! Error: StaticInjectorError(...)[BsDropdownDirective ->
>   ComponentLoaderFactory]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[BsDropdownDirective -> ComponentLoaderFactory]:

Comment: find this ref: 
1. https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input/issues/125#issuecomment-377675844
2.https://github.com/webcat12345/ngx-intl-tel-input/pull/128

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix it by going to index.js file in

```
node_modules\ngx-intl-tel-input
```

and in this section

```
NgxIntlTelInputModule.decorators = [{
    type: NgModule,
    args: [{ imports: [ CommonModule, FormsModule, BsDropdownModule ], ...
```

I changed **`BsDropdownModule`** to **`BsDropdownModule.forRoot()`**

P.S Don't forget to call `ng serve` again after you make this change.

This is of course a patch and should be still fixed in this package otherwise, once package is updated, changes will be overriden.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin - intl-input-phone.

```
npm i intl-input-phone
```

[See the NPM link for more information npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl-input-phone)

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/surajmathe/intl-input-phone)

[Demo Link 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/intl-input-phone-demo)

[Demo Link 2](https://intl-input-phone-demo.stackblitz.io/)

Answer (score 0):

**Hope This helps**

In App.module

```
import { NgxIntlTelInputModule } from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';
imports: [
   
    NgxIntlTelInputModule
]
```

In your component  html :

```
  <ngx-intl-tel-input [preferredCountries]="['es']" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true" name="phoneNumber"
              formControlName="phoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
```